# Can a comma be placed before a modified subject?

Tags: punctuation, adverb-placement

- Severely damaged human civilization dreams of peace.

Do you think that a comma is essential after *severely damaged*? If it is necessary, please say why I should use comma.

Comment: Uh ... Do you know any civilizations that are not human? Do tell.

Comment: Sure. Plenty.  They're fictional, of course, but we can certainly use the English language to talk about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Severely damaged human civilization dreams of peace.

Here, "severely damaged" is an adjectival phrase describing human civilization, as in "A severely damaged civilization".

> Severely damaged, human civilization dreams of peace.

Now, the meaning is "Having been severely damaged, human civilization dreams of peace."

Without the comma, you are simply describing human civilization as it is: severely damaged and dreaming of peace. With a comma, you are implying that human civilization dreams of peace *because of* being severely damaged (presumably by war). The difference is essentially between "damaged" as an adjective ("These are damaged goods") and "damaged" as the past tense of a verb ("The goods were damaged in the accident").